# Scroll the iFrame content for Safari, iOS5

Tags: css, ipad, ios5, iframe, safari

I'm building a splitview page to be added inside of iOS application, using jQuery, jQuery.mobile, [asyraf9 splitview plugin](https://github.com/asyraf9) and cubiq's iScroll. As a typical splitview, it has a sidebar in the left and content area in the right side.

This is the image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfUyE.png

I prevent the touchmove with simple js-line

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
```

and let the content area to be scrolled with iScroll.

However, one of the pages should have an embedded iFrame from another domain. I don't use iScroll for this kind of pages. I have the links inside of iFrame, so I need to be able to click on them.

```
<div class="iframe-wrapper">
<iframe id="iframe-element" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

It has the CSS like

```
.iframe-wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: 670px;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    overflow: scroll;
}

#iframe-element {
    height: 100%;
    width: 670px;
}
```

I load the src for iFrame via javascript when the needed page was called

```
$('#page-1-3')
    .one('pageshow', function() {
        $('#iframe-element').attr('src', 'http://www.somewebsite.com');
    });
```

But while it works great for Safari with iOS6, it doesn't work for iOS5. Sometimes it scrolls the content inside the iFrame, but at the same time, it moves the whole page up or down, even I have prevented such a behavior for the rest of the page. In case it scrolls it down, it doesn't render the content below the end of the page (I have it more than on one page).

I've tried many ways of solutions and searching through the web, but no one of them seems to be work. It either scroll the content not good, or not render everything, or just don't scroll the content inside at all.

Could anyone recommend me something useful about it, please?